# Create Sidebar or Vertical Menu in Vaadin

Tags: css, sass, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-valo-theme

How can I create a **VerticalMenu** or **Sidebar** in Vaadin? Is there any specific component or Have I do programatically and using CSS?

I would like to create something like [Vaadin Demo](http://demo.vaadin.com/valo-theme/#!buttons-and-links):

[image]

I'm using the new Valo Theme.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

well to be able to create a responsive behaviour for your application you'd have to use CSS. Like Zigac mentioned Vaadin has some styles already written for some components (such as our menu here) but you'd wanna apply more eventually...

check out the new [Dashboard demo](http://dashboard.demo.vaadin.com/) with the Valo theme and responsiveness! It's a more comprehensive example of styling components and implements the same logic as the Valo Theme Demo. You can view the source code [here](https://github.com/vaadin/dashboard-demo/tree/master/src/main/java/com/vaadin/demo/dashboard)

Basically what it does is create a [menu](https://github.com/vaadin/dashboard-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vaadin/demo/dashboard/view/DashboardMenu.java) as a CustomComponent and a content area as a CssLayout. Whenever a component is clicked in the menu it will call the corresponding view in the content area of the [MainView](https://github.com/vaadin/dashboard-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vaadin/demo/dashboard/view/MainView.java)

For example one of the views is the [DashboardView](https://github.com/vaadin/dashboard-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vaadin/demo/dashboard/view/dashboard/DashboardView.java) which is the first view the user sees. It's a responsive VerticalLayout with responsive compnents on it.

You can view the styling techniques (in Sass) for the different views [here](https://github.com/vaadin/dashboard-demo/tree/master/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/dashboard/views)

Here are some code sinppets:

**MainView.java**

```
public class MainView extends HorizontalLayout {

public MainView() {
    //This is the root of teh application it
    //extends a HorizontalLayout
    setSizeFull();
    addStyleName("mainview");

    //here we add the Menu component
    addComponent(new DashboardMenu());

    //add the content area and style
    ComponentContainer content = new CssLayout();
    content.addStyleName("view-content");
    content.setSizeFull();
    addComponent(content);

    setExpandRatio(content, 1.0f);

    new DashboardNavigator(content);
}
}
```

**DashboardMenu.java**

```
public DashboardMenu() {
    addStyleName("valo-menu");
    setSizeUndefined();
    DashboardEventBus.register(this);

    //add components to the menu (buttons, images..etc)
    setCompositionRoot(buildContent());
}
```

**DashboardView.java**

```
public DashboardView() {
    addStyleName(ValoTheme.PANEL_BORDERLESS);
    setSizeFull();
    DashboardEventBus.register(this);

    root = new VerticalLayout();
    root.setSizeFull();
    root.setMargin(true);
    root.addStyleName("dashboard-view");
    setContent(root);

    //this allows you to use responsive styles
    //on the root element
    Responsive.makeResponsive(root);

    //build your dashboard view
    root.addComponent(buildHeader());

    root.addComponent(buildSparklines());

    Component content = buildContent();
    root.addComponent(content);

    //set the content area position on screen
    root.setExpandRatio(content, 1);
...
```

and here is the styleName "dashboard-view" in the style sheet

**dashboardview.scss**

```
@mixin dashboard-dashboard-view {

.dashboard-view.dashboard-view {
//Styles for all devices
padding: $view-padding;
overflow: visible;

.sparks {
  @include valo-panel-style;
  margin-bottom: round($view-padding / 3);

  //styles for a tablet
  @include width-range($max: 680px) {
    .spark {
      width: 50%;
    }
    .spark:nth-child(2n+1) {
      border-left: none;
    }
    .spark:nth-child(n+3) {
      border-top: valo-border($strength: 0.3);
    }
  }
...
```

Answer (score 7):

For that exact design you do not need no CSS coding, all the styles are provided with compiled Valo theme. You just have to use appropriate styles on your components and layouts.

GIT links for that exact (Vaadin Demo) implementation:

[ValoThemeUI.java](https://github.com/vaadin/valo-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vaadin/tests/themes/valo/ValoThemeUI.java) - layouting valo-menu on page

[ValoMenuLayout.java](https://github.com/vaadin/valo-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vaadin/tests/themes/valo/ValoMenuLayout.java) - layouting components inside valo-menu

Comment: There seems to be a warning on https://github.com/vaadin/valo-demo that the example is deprecated.